# .NET apps requires auth multiple times and puts encrypted strings into the URL after first log in

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, forms-authentication

I've got two .NET apps that have a strange behavior of requiring authentication several times, but only once per page request. So I would log in, it would take me to the page that looked like I successfully logged in, then when I click on another menu option, it would ask me to log in again. Sometimes every single different page I would click on would ask me to log in, but after doing so I could access that page. If it didn't do that behavior then after a random time it would ask me to log in again.

Also something I noticed that encrypted data gets stored in the URL.

- Step 1: Go to website, login, everything appears normal.
- Step 2: Click on menu link within app, it goes to a URL that looks like this:

> https://www.mydomain.com/myapp/(X(1)S(hr4zvojplikcza2osx4i5ksk))/SomePage.aspx

- Step 3: Click that link, it requires me to login again and now all URLs have that weird string in it. If I login a second time, that weird string becomes even longer.

If I just type in the page URL without the (X(1)S(hr4zvojplikcza2osx4i5ksk)), it works fine and does not require me to log in again. But every link in the app off of the app's root is prepended with that string. Also this problem dissappears if I restart the app pool, but at a random later time, it will rear it's head again.

The apps use forms auth. What's going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encrypted url is used in place of an Authentication Cookie. This occurs when Cookieless is enabled in your web.config.

You can find out more here: [MSDN Cookieless Sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx). and here: [MSDN Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.formscookiename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Change Cookieless to UseCookies.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
      cookieless="UseCookies"
      name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
```